# Navigation bar at bottom, centerd - CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I need a quick tip how to manage with some problem. I've created a navi bar and center it so now its in the middle of page no matter how big or small is screen, but how to make that bar to stay on the bottom of page ? I know that when i add a `height` to `.MainContainer` it push that bar to the bottom but i want to make it dependless of constant height. Big thanks for any advice!

---

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>  
<body>
    <div class="MainContainer">
    </div>  
    <div id="MenuContainer">
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="x"><a title="1" href="indexX-1.html" >1</a></li>
            <li class="x"><a title="2" href="#" >2</a></li>
            <li class="x"><a title="3" href="#" >3</a></li>
            <li class="x"><a title="4" href="#" >4</a></li>
            <li class="x"><a title="5" href="#" >5</a></li>
            <li class="contact" class="last"><a title="6" href="#" >6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.MainContainer {
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
.MenuContainer {
    height: 70px;
    bottom:0;
}
ul#navigation {
    height: 70px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0;    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Cham-WebFont', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
ul#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .75em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#navigation li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: don't give youe id's and classes the same name. It doesn't confuse machines, but it will confuse you.

Comment: yea, You are right .. confuse is omething i want to avoid :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By making `html` and `body` `height:100%` and applying fixed positioning to your navigation.

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

ul#navigation {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqKpe/1/  
Feel free to resize the window and see that your navigation always remains at the bottom.

Comment: And centering with `left: 0; right: 0;`. Also the `ul` part of the selectors isn't necessary. The id is sufficient.

Comment: @FelipeAls centering is done by `width:100%` in combination with the already there in the OP `text-align:center`. I agree with the `ul` part in the selector but the OP has it already there so I left it for clarity.

Comment: Big thanks @Bazzz for Your time and support it solve my problem :D 
-FelipeAls thanks for advice, i'm still lerning to manage my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YG5vE/) for you

You have a typo:

```
.MenuContainer {
    height: 70px;
    bottom:0;
}
```

should be:

```
#MenuContainer {
        height: 70px;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

according to your HTML. Also add `position:fixed;`:

```
 #MenuContainer {
            height: 70px;
            bottom:0;
            position:fixed;
        }
```

Comment: *update* comment no longer valid. OP has changed the HTML. ---->   You make some valid points but, this doesn't even do anything with the navigation, and certainly doesn't make it stay at the bottom of the page as requested by the OP.